# PHP Checkbox Array

Tags: php, json

All,

When a form gets posted, I get some checkbox values like the below:

```
 [chk0] => Array ( 
    [1] => on 
    [57] => on 
    [83] => on 
  ) 
 [chk1] => Array ( 
    [69] => on 
    [71] => on
 )
 [chk1001] => on 
 [chk1005] => on
 [chk1008] => on
```

Using PHP,How can I construct a JSON request with 2 arrays like this by using the above variables? All checkboxes are prefixed with "chk". If the checkbox is an array and has values, the first JSON request should be generated. For all those which are not arrays, it should generate the second one.

```
//JSON Request 1
       "data1":
            [
                {
                    "checkboxval": true,
                    "id": 1
                },
                {
                    "checkboxval": true,
                    "id": 57
                },
                {
                    "checkboxval": true,
                    "id": 83
                },
                {
                    "checkboxval": true,
                    "id": 69
                },
                {
                    "checkboxval": true,
                    "id": 71
                }
            ]

//JSON Request 2:
   "data2":
        [
            {
                "checkboxval": true,
                "id": 1001
            },
            {
                "checkboxval": true,
                "id": 1005
            },
            {
                "checkboxval": true,
                "id": 1008
            }
        ]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$data = array(
    "data1" => array(),
    "data2" => array(),
);
foreach($_POST as $key => $value)
{
    if(preg_match('/^chk/',$key))
    {
        if(is_array($value))
        {
            foreach($value as $id => $on)
                $data["data1"][] = array("checkboxval"=>true,"id"=>$id);
        }
        else
            $data["data2"][] = array("checkboxval"=>true,"id"=>str_replace("chk","",$key));
    }
}
$json = json_encode($data);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I don't think it's working for the first case.